# what is the backbone of your/most RSS reader iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rss, blogs, blogger

I am making a iphone app for my local school.
I have a good grasp on obj-c and stuff.

Once I am done with this app the students will be supplying 100% of the content through blogger or something else.

my question is what service (if any) would you use for the RSS feed?
blogger? etc???
I need it to be simple enough that kids can summit the content.

in the app there will be a NEWS, EVENTS, BLOG, and CONTACT pages

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use wordpress or blogger, depending on your own taste. Both can publish rss feeds like the ones you're looking for.

A more interesting option might be google docs. 
-Create spreadsheet and press press the "share with everyone" under sharing options
-Go to "Files->Publish as web page", press publish and check the flag that makes it automatically republish on changes
-When it has been published you can press the "web page" select-box and click "RSS".

And bingo, you've got a spreadsheet wherein you can publish all your data. Of course it doesn't have quite as much interface-niceties as wordpress or blogger, but you get full control over your feed.

Here's an example of a feed from a google doc I just made:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AnY80NT8R-0UdEVIWEh0YUZ3eGdHQ1lBalRfUGZpZkE/od6/public/basic?alt=rss